# fit controls to screen vba

Tags: vba, excel

i'm trying to fit the user form to screen on diifernet screens.

the userform was first managed in my work screen and i fit it to my screen but  when i'm trying the userform on other screens part of it vanished.

i can't put the whole code in here but i will put just the sub that suppose to fit to screen:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim w As Long, h As Long
Application.Visible = False

With Me
        rMaxHeight = Application.Height
        rMaxWidth = Application.Width
        If .Height > Application.Height - 10 Then
        rNormalHeight = rMaxHeight * 0.85
        Else
        rNormalHeight = Me.Height
        End If
        If .Width > Application.Width - 10 Then
        rNormalWidth = rMaxWidth * 0.85
        Else
        rNormalWidth = Me.Width
        End If

        .StartUpPosition = 1
        .Left = 0
        .Top = 0
         FitSize
...

Private Sub FitSize()
Dim h, w
Dim c As Control
Dim PHeight, PWidth As Double

PHeight = rNormalHeight / Me.Height
PWidth = rNormalWidth / Me.Width
h = 0: w = 0

If PHeight = 1 And PWidth = 1 Then Exit Sub

    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If c.Visible Then
            If c.Top + c.Height > h Then h = (c.Top + c.Height) ' * PHeight

            If c.Left + c.Width > w Then w = (c.Left + c.Width) ' * PWidth

            If Not TypeName(c) = "Image" Or TypeName(c) = "ListBox" Then   c.FontSize = c.FontSize * ((PHeight + PWidth) / 2)
        End If
    Next c

    If h > 0 And w > 0 Then
        With Me
            .Width = w + 40
            .Height = h + 40
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

hope you could help me with that

Thank you all
sefi

Comment: And thus spoke Google: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/500411-userform-autofit-screen-size.html

Comment: This is a surprisingly involved problem, which is one of the reasons that modern GUI toolkits can automatically position the controls given a higher-level logical layout of them. Unfortunately, VBA doesn't have a modern GUI library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and thank for everyone that tried to help me. 
I found the solution to this problem by fitting the controls to the proportion of the screen copared with the original form.

At first step you need to calculate the proportion:

```
Dim PHeight, PWidth As Double
'define form size compared with the original size of the form
rMaxHeight = Application.Height
rMaxWidth = Application.Width
If Me.Height > Application.Height Then
rNormalHeight = rMaxHeight * 0.85
Else
rNormalHeight = Me.Height
End If
If Me.Width > Application.Width Then
rNormalWidth = rMaxWidth * 0.85
Else
rNormalWidth = Me.Width
End If
 'normal is the size needed in normal mode before the form get to maximize mode
 'we want to calculate the needed divided to the orignal
PHeight = rNormalHeight / Me.Height
PWidth = rNormalWidth / Me.Width
```

now we call `fitsize()`

```
Private Sub FitSize()
Dim h, w
Dim c As Control

h = 0: w = 0

If PHeight = 1 And PWidth = 1 Then Exit Sub ' if the it is the original size of the form- don't bother...

'loop on the form controls
For Each c In Me.Controls
   If c.Visible Then                                     ' just visible controls
      c.Top = c.Top * PHeight                            ' fit to proportion of the screen compared with the original form
      c.Height = c.Height * PHeight
      If c.Top + c.Height > h Then h = c.Top + c.Height  ' collect the height needed from the controls

      c.Left = c.Left * PWidth                           ' fit to proportion of the screen compared with the original form
      c.Width = c.Width * PWidth
      If c.Left + c.Width > w Then w = c.Left + c.Width  ' collect the height needed from the controls

      'fit the font for the text controls
      If Not TypeName(c) = "Image" Or TypeName(c) = "ListBox" Then c.FontSize = c.FontSize * ((PHeight + PWidth) / 2)
      End If
Next c

'define the size needed form the specific screen
If h > 0 And w > 0 Then
    With Me
      .Width = w + 40
      .Height = h + 40
      .StartUpPosition = 0
      .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
      .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
     End With
End If

End Sub
```

this code will define the size needed in each screen by the proportion that calculated in the needed value divded to the original value.

Try it and tell me if it works.

thank you all
sefi

Comment: Be careful with Font size+WordWrap when you shrink controls. You may even need to decrease the font size for even smaller screens.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, i know you said it before but i didn't think that it will be that easy. i will be careful with the fonr but it  basically calculates the proportion so when the screen is smaller the proportion will be smaller too.

Answer (score 2):

You can either Re-position every single control in the UserForm with VBA or simply enable ScrollBars for the UserForm object so they can access all the elements with a bit of scrolling.

Change the *ScrollBars* property of the UserForm to like **`3 - fmScrollBarsBoth`** as the default is *`0 - fmScrollBarsNone`*

[image: UserForm ScrollBars Property]

Then you need to figure out how tall and wide it needs to be:

- **ScrollHeight**
- **ScrollWidth**

[image: ScrobbHeight-Width]

Comment: @sefia Sounds like **ScrollHeight** and **ScrollWidth** is zero? You need to make it bigger or equal to the UserForm's **Height** and **Width** (the scroll bars takes some space as well, so count it in).

Comment: do you mean that i need to defone the userform height and width in the scrollheight and scrollwidth again? if , for exapmle, my form height is 761 and form width is 1246 then Ineed to defin ScrollHeight = 761 and ScrollWidth = 1246? Thank you

Comment: thank you it workes but the problem is that the orginal screen was really bigger than the laptop screen that i'm chaking it now and you need to scroll a lot and it becomes really not comfortable to use. maybe there is an option to fit the screen with the controls to some size that it will be more comfortable to use?

Comment: That's what I said first place - re-position every control (you may even need to decrease font size for labels too. Honestly, if I have to fill in a UserForm that big, I will think it's a bad design as it will scare people off, MultiPage can be used to categorize details, even Frames with dynamic visibility and position can make it a pleasure. And that can fit into a 11 inch laptop screen.